# how to have fread perform like read.delim

Tags: r, data.table

I've got a large tab-delimited data table that I am trying to read into R using the data.table package fread function. However, fread encounters an error. If I use read.delim, the table is read in properly, but I can't figure out how to configure fread such that it handles the data properly.

In an attempt to find a solution, I've installed the development version of data.table, so I am currently running data.table v1.9.7, under R v3.2.2, running on Ubuntu 15.10.

I've isolated the problem to a few lines from my large table, and you can [download it here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34644229/problemRows.txt).

When I used fread:

```
> fread('problemRows.txt')
Error in fread("problemRows.txt") : 
  Expecting 8 cols, but line 3 contains text after processing all cols. It is very likely that this is due to one or more fields having embedded sep=',' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes. fread cannot handle such ambiguous cases and those lines may not have been read in as expected. Please read the section on quotes in ?fread.
```

I tried using the parameters used by read.delim:

```
fread('problemRows.txt', sep="\t", quote="\"")
```

but I get the same error.

Any thoughts on how to get this to read in properly? I'm not sure what exactly the problem is.

Thanks!

Comment: you also have an extra "double quote" on you second line of code

Answer (score 3):

With this recent commit [c1b7cda](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/c1b7cda17f5f3f765fc6c15872ee542ecf68853c), `fread`'s quote logic got a bit cleverer in handling such tricky cases. With this:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
fread("my_file.txt")
```

should just work. The error message is now more informative as well if it is unable to handle. See [#1462](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1462).

---

As explained in the comments, specifying the quotes argument did the trick.

```
fread("my_file.txt", quote="")
```